# Последовательность целых чисел

Tags: delphi

Дано целое число `N` (> 2). Последовательность целых чисел `AK` определяется следующим образом:

> A1 = 1, A2 = 2, A3 = 3,
>
> AK = AK¡1 + AK¡2 ¡ 2¢AK¡3, K = 4, 5, : : : .

Вывести элементы A1, A2, : : : , AN.

Comment: Попробуйте, с ошибками или совсем-не-пониманием-алгоритма - сюда. А вообще значки какие-то странные) Я правда не математик, но все же - может как-то расшифруете?

Comment: @0ffControl, напишите свои соображения по решению задачи.

Comment: Ребят если у меня были какие либо соображения я бы сдесь бы не писал)
Такие значки у меня в учебнике...если чесно я сам не доконца понел

Answer (score 1):

```
for i := 0 to N do
writeln(intToStr(i));
```

Тяжело, неправдали?

Answer (score 1):

Полная чушь. Какой-то, судя по всему, пропустил это все через оптическое распознавание, в результате получилась куча опечаток. Подозреваю, что должно быть так:

[image: формула]

Тогда решение задачи на псевдо-коде выглядит так:

```
A1 = 1
A2 = 2
A3 = 3
for (i = 1 .. N) do
  print A1
  tmp = A1
  A1 = A2
  A2 = A3
  A3 = A3 + A2 + 2 * tmp
```

Comment: наверно, я тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту, про плохое распознавание